# Why the three characteristics not included in Satipatthana Sutta?

Tags: mindfulness, three-characteristics

Why are the [three marks (consolidated)](https://suttacentral.net/an3.136/en/sujato?lang=en&layout=sidebyside&reference=none&notes=asterisk&highlight=true&script=latin) not directly included in the [Satipatthana Sutta](https://suttacentral.net/mn10/en/sujato?lang=en&layout=sidebyside&reference=none&notes=sidenotes&highlight=false&script=latin) - supposedly the most important of all discourses?  Not in the section of principles, but indirectly with regards to the body:

> *They meditate observing the body as liable to originate, as liable to vanish, and as liable to both originate and vanish.*

Perhaps it is due to the later historical ontological organization of those three messages? Any tangential ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

While the Satipatthana Sutta is a fake later construction, generally when impermanence is mentioned in a sutta it also infers unsatisfactoriness & not-self because the suttas say: *that which is impermanent is unsatisfactory; that which is unsatisfactory is not-self* ([SN 22.15](https://suttacentral.net/sn22.15/en/bodhi?lang=en&reference=none&highlight=false)).

> MORE TO IT THAN JUST IMPERMANENCE
>
> Now, observe that in the realization of impermanence there is the
> realization of many other things simultaneously. When impermanence is
> truly seen, this characteristic of impermanence is also the
> characteristic of dukkham, namely, it is ugly and unbearable. We will
> see the characteristic of not-self in it, also. Because these things
> are always changing, impermanent, unsatisfactory, and beyond our
> control, we realize anatta, also. Then we will see that they are void
> of selfhood, which is sunnata. We will see that they are just thus
> like that. Impermanence is just thus, just like that, thusness. And
> so, tathata is seen as well.
>
> Please understand that the realizations of these truths are
> interrelated. From seeing impermanence, we see unsatisfactoriness, see
> anatta, see sunnata; see tathata, and see idappaccayata
> (conditionality, the law of cause and effect), also. Each continues
> into the next. A complete realization of impermanence must include
> un­satisfactoriness, not-self, voidness, thusness, and the law of
> conditionality. When all of these are seen, then impermanence is seen
> completely in the most profound way.
>
> [Ajahn Buddhadasa](https://dhammatalks.net/Books3/Bhikkhu_Buddhadasa_Anapanasati_Mindfulness_with_Breathing.htm)